# ASP.NET MVC check if ActionResult is null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm calling a partial view like this:

```
@Html.Action("_EditTranslationsList", new { id = Model.Id })
```

And that ActionResult returns a list of items from database and I show them in a table. But if the list is not found in the SQL Query, the action result returns null. I wanted to try this but it is not working:

```
@if (@Html.Action("_EditTranslationsList", new { id = Model.Id }) == null)
{
//something
}
else
{
//something
}
```

Everytime, even if there is a list, the first case happens. I tried returning Content("") instead of null but then I have problem with converting to string because if there is a list, it cannot be converted to string to check it and then I get an error.

How can I create a case which will happen if the Action Result List is null?

Comment: Your conditional check should be done in the `_EditTranslationsList()` method - return one view if the result of the query is null and another view if not

Comment: The `_EditTranslationsList` action method must be returning a view (partial view in ur case) right?
So
you can write following code in your view :
`@if(Model==null or Model.id==null)
{
<div>No results found</div>
}else
{
//bind ur list here
}`
or u can also follow the @Stephen Muecke Approach